# Is there a flaw in Jon/Dr. Manhattan's logic?

Tags: dc, watchmen, dr-manhattan

*First of all, I read the comic book in German. Therefore translations are mine according to my understanding. So translation might be an issue to my actual question, though I doubt it, since I watched the movie in English and am still puzzled.*

The reason

> Jon returns to Earth

is the

> thermodynamical miracle of life, which is astronomically improbable.

Ok, granted, the probability of Laurie's life is *very* small. However, the probability of life itself, given the vastness of the universe, is not small at all and Jon knows that. So to witness life

> he would not have had to return to the Earth, but he could just have teleported from planet to planet.

Is Dr. Manhattan's logic flawed? (Or is my understanding, or am I just missing something?)

Comment: Is this question actually asking "How probable is life developing, really?"

Comment: @The Nate: No. And I already kind of answered this in my question (though did not elaborate) ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've missed the point of his realization. [Quoting from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Manhattan#Events_of_Watchmen):

> he brings Laurie to Mars to discuss why he should do anything to aid
>   humanity, an argument Laurie inadvertently wins when she goes through
>   her life and realizes to her shock that her father is the Comedian, a
>   man whom she despised for sexually assaulting her mother. From that
>   revelation, Doctor Manhattan is amazed by the improbable chances that
>   occurred to result in the birth of Laurie, which he sees as a stunning
>   "thermodynamic miracle". By extension, this miracle can apply to any
>   living thing on Earth, and so **Doctor Manhattan decides to return to
>   Earth to protect humanity rather than disregarding it as
>   insignificant.**

The [Watchmen Wikia explains](http://watchmen.wikia.com/wiki/Jon_Osterman#Transformation) his uncaring attitude towards humans:

> After his transformation, Jon begins to experience time in a
>   non-linear, "quantum" fashion, and it is implied that he is aware of
>   and experiencing all the moments of his life simultaneously. Jon is
>   not omniscient; he remains reliant on his intellect and sensory
>   experience to reach conclusions, but his range of sensory data has
>   been abruptly extended, in proportion to the lessening of his
>   emotional capacities. This often leads him to arrive at conclusions
>   greatly different from those available to normal humans. However,
>   during the course of Watchmen he displays powerful emotion several
>   times. **His apparent lack of sentiment is more a matter of radically
>   altered priorities, owing to a colossal, unbridgeable gap of
>   perception between Jon and the rest of humanity.**
>
> He subscribes to a deterministic view of events. During the period in
>   which Doctor Manhattan is a crime-fighter (at the behest of the
>   government), he states that the morality of such activities escapes
>   him. **From his radically altered perspective, almost all human concerns
>   appear pointless and without obvious merit.**

Comment: Ah, so it's not that *life* itself is the reason for his return, but the change in his attitude towards life on Earth. I never looked at it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> And yet, in each human coupling, a thousand million sperm vie for a single egg. Multiply those odds by countless generations, against the odds of your ancestors being alive; meeting; siring this precise son; that exact daughter... Until your mother loves a man she has every reason to hate, and of that union, of the thousand million children competing for fertilization, it was you, only you, that emerged. To distill so specific a form from that chaos of improbability, like turning air to gold... that is the crowning unlikelihood. The thermodynamic miracle."

It's not the odds of life evolving, it's the rarity of Laurie existing, given the events of her mother's life, and the extraordinary event that led to her conception, that is the miracle.